# Breaking link with other turtle when x amount of patches away?

Tags: netlogo

How can I get turtles to break a link when they stray a x amount of patches away from the turtle they are linked with? I have tried this line of code which I thought would work `to break-link if cooperator link in-radius linking-radius > max-link-radius [ ask one-of links [ die ] ] end`, but I get the error 'link expected 2 inputs, a number and a number'. Any help would be appreciated, thank you. Code posted below

```
turtles-own [ energy ] 

breed [ cooperators cooperator ] 
breed [ uncooperators uncooperator ]




to setup 
  ca
  ask patches [
    set pcolor green
  ]
  create-uncooperators num-uncooperators [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color red
    set energy random 100
  ]set-default-shape turtles "person"
  create-cooperators num-cooperators [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color yellow
    set energy random 100
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  if not any? turtles [ stop ] 
  ask cooperators [
    set energy energy - 1
    move
    communicate
    cooperate
    break-link
  ]
  ask uncooperators [
    set energy energy - 1
    move 
  ]
  tick
end

to move
  lt 50
  rt 50
  fd 1
end



to communicate
  if count my-links < 1 [
   create-link-to one-of uncooperators in-radius linking-radius
  ]
end

to break-link
  if cooperator link in-radius linking-radius > max-link-radius [ ask one-of links [ die ] ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please only post relevant code, usually for NetLogo that is the procedure that is giving you the error and the procedure that calls it. So this is the line giving the error message:

```
to break-link
  if cooperator link in-radius linking-radius > max-link-radius
  [ ask one-of links [ die ]
  ]
end
```

NetLogo is telling you that it doesn't know which `link` you mean because links are identified by two numbers - the turtle at each end. If you look at your code, you have the word `link` followed by two numbers (the variables in-radius and linking-radius) but those are not turtle identifiers. I think you want to do something like ask the long links to break, in which case you are mixing physical/spatial distances with network distances (how many links to pass along). Is something like this what you want?

```
to break-link
  ask cooperators
  [ if distance one-of link-neighbors > max-link-radius
    [ ask one-of links [ die ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

`link-neigbors` is used to find the turtles that are connected to the turtle doing the asking. But this is not going to achieve your objective because a random link dies, not the one that meets the distance condition. Maybe this (not tested):

```
to break-link         ; called by a cooperator turtle
  let furthest-friend max-one-of link-neighbors [distance myself]
  if distance furthest-friend > max-link-radius
  [ ask link-with furthest-friend [ die ]
  ]
end
```